# Quantization of complex scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

I'm learning Peskin's qft now and I'm a little confused about problem 2.2 .

Suppose I write the field $\phi(x)$ as:

$\phi(x) =\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}} (a_{p}e^{-ipx}+b_{p}e^{ipx})$

I know that $b_p$ should be written as $b_p^\dagger$ because it annihilate antiparticle, otherwise $b_p$ creates particle with negative energy.

However, when I calculate the Hamiltonian, all I got is:

$\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_{p}(a^\dagger_{p}a_{p}+b^\dagger_{p}b_{p})$

In my result, the $b$ particles create positive energy as $a$ particle did. I'm not sure if I did something wrong in calculation or there are some other explanation in the result.[image]

Comment: $b^\dagger b=bb^\dagger+\text{constant}$.

Comment: What I mean is: It seems like if I regards $b$ as creation operator in my field expression, the hamiltonian is still fine, which is contradictory to $b$ creating negative energy then hamiltonian has no bounds.

Comment: hmm $[H,b]=-E b$ and $[H,b^\dagger]=+E b^\dagger$. You are not free to choose; only one of $b,b^\dagger$ increases the energy of a state, the other one decreases it.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, Peskin gives the following action:
$$
\mathcal{S} = \int d^4 \left[ \partial_{\mu} \phi^{\ast} \partial^{\mu} \phi - m^2 \phi^{\ast} \phi \right].
$$
Let's begin by considering the classical field theory. The equation of motion is
$$
\left( \partial^2 + m^2 \right) \phi = 0
$$
(and its complex conjugate). A general solution to this equation is given by
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_\mathbf{p}}} \left( a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} + i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} + b_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} - i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} \right),
$$
where $E_{\mathbf{p}} = \sqrt{|\mathbf{p}|^2 + m^2}$. At this point, the quantities $a_{\mathbf{p}}$ and $b_{\mathbf{p}}$ are just some complex functions of momentum. We can also write down the classical Hamiltonian of this system, where the conjugate momentum is
$$
\pi(\mathbf{x},t) = \partial_t \phi^{\ast}(x,t) = - i \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{E_\mathbf{p}}{2}} \left( a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\ast} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} - i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} - b_{\mathbf{p}}^{\ast} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} + i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} \right)
$$
(and its complex conjugate).

Now we go to the quantum theory, where the fields $\phi$ and $\pi$ (and therefore the coefficients $a_{\mathbf{p}}$ and $b_{\mathbf{p}}$) become operators. The starting point of quantization is the equal-time canonical commutation relations:
$$
[\phi(\mathbf{x},t),\pi(\mathbf{y},t)] = [\phi^{\ast}(\mathbf{x},t),\pi^{\ast}(\mathbf{y},t)] = i \delta^3(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})
$$
We cannot *assume* at this point that $a_{\mathbf{p}}$ and $b_{\mathbf{p}}$ are bosonic annihilation operators, we need to actually calculate their commutation relations from the above equations. Inverting the above formulae, we have
$$
a_{\mathbf{p}} = e^{- i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} \int d^3 x \, e^{- i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \left( \sqrt{\frac{E_{\mathbf{p}}}{2}} \, \phi(\mathbf{x},t) - i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}} \, \pi^{\ast}(\mathbf{x},t) \right),
$$
$$
b_{\mathbf{p}} = e^{- i E_{\mathbf{p}} t} \int d^3 x \, e^{- i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \left( \sqrt{\frac{E_{\mathbf{p}}}{2}} \, \phi(\mathbf{x},t) + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}} \, \pi^{\ast}(\mathbf{x},t) \right).
$$
Now we can compute the commutators directly. They are
$$
[a_{\mathbf{p}},a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}'}] = - (2 \pi)^3 \delta^3(\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{p}'), \qquad [b_{\mathbf{p}},b^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}'}] = (2 \pi)^3 \delta^3(\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{p}').
$$
As you can see, one of these commutators is the wrong sign compared to the usual bosonic commutation relations, and as a result the construction of the usual bosonic Fock space proceeds differently. (In particular, $[a^{\dagger} a, a^{\dagger}] \propto - a^{\dagger} $ so $a^{\dagger}$ is actually a lowering operator.) To get the usual commutation relations, we should define
$$
\tilde{a}_{\mathbf{p}} = a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}, \quad \tilde{a}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}} = a_{-\mathbf{p}}, \quad \tilde{b}_{\mathbf{p}} = b_{\mathbf{p}}, \quad \tilde{b}^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}} = b^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf{p}}.
$$
This gives us the usual result. In textbooks they often write down the initial expansion in such a way so that the answer comes out correctly, but in practice one needs to go through the above procedure (until you've done it enough times that it has become automatic).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid what is wrong is in your initial writing.

A complex scalar field should be written as
$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}} (a_p e^{-ipx} + b_p^\dagger e^{ipx})$
And, by complex conjugation,
$\phi^*(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}} (a_p^\dagger e^{ipx} + b_p e^{-ipx})$
Clearly $a_p^\dagger \neq b_p^\dagger$ as these operators create particles of opposite charge. However in both cases $\omega_p = \sqrt{\vec p^2 +m^2} \gt 0$.

To get the normal ordering of the $b's$ operators, at the end of the demonstration you have to apply the equal-time commutation relations
$[b_p, b_{p'}^\dagger] = (2 \pi)^3 \delta^3 (\vec p - \vec p')$

Note: Your notation of the $b$ operator as creator is confusing. The notation used in literature for a complex scalar field and reported here is a generalization of the notation applied to a real scalar field.

Comment: I know that your answer is the standard result. What I am confused is: what if I do the substitution $b^\dagger\rightarrow b$? Is there any consequence that violates principles?

Comment: @user189783. We should distinguish between the notation and the meaning. If you assume that $b$ is a creator of antiparticles, you have to apply the commutation relations consistently. That is you have to swap the $b$ and the $b^\dagger$, and so you get the normal ordering (consistent with your convention). However in the literature what is used is what is in my post and the reason is that it is a generalization of the notation for a real scalar field, formulated as a superposition of single solutions and their complex conjugates.