# Explanation for vanishing term in mode expansion of complex scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am working on the mode expansion of the complex scalar field.
This [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535149/quantization-of-complex-scalar-field) shows most of the relevant steps. In particular, I am interested in the second to last line.
I have plugged in $phi(x)$ and its conjugate and derivatives into the hamiltonian for the complex scalar field and have gotten to this expression:
$$\int \frac{d^3p}{2E_p}[(E_p^2 +p^2+m^2)(a_p^\dagger a_p+b_p b_p^\dagger)-(E_p^2 +p^2-m^2)(b_p a_pe^{-i2E_p t}+a_p^\dagger b_p^\dagger e^{i2E_p t})]$$
Here, the second term is supposed to be $0$ and we get the expected result after a little algebraic manipulation using the on-shell condition:
$$\int d^3p E_p (a_p^\dagger a_p +b_p^\dagger b_p)$$
But I just don't understand why the previous term vanished. What is the explanation for it?

Answer (score 1):

In the link you provided, the second term has a factor $(-E_p^2 + p^2 + m^2)$, instead of $-(E_p^2+p^2-m^2)$ as you wrote. It vanishes due to the on-shell condition $E_p^2 = m^2 + p^2$